# Convert linked list into binary search tree?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

Given a Circularly doubly linked list... How can i convert it into Binary Search Tree..

The question is found at 
http://rajeevprasanna.blogspot.com/2011/02/convert-binary-tree-into-doubly-linked.html

I tried to write the code for the same, but it choked!! Please, some suggestions here would be good. Also, how can i find the middle of the linked list.. Please talk in terms of code (C or C++ code) and if possible small example would be good else fine.

Going through the article(URL) that i provided above, BST to Linked List was a good excercise. I tried to follow on the same principal, but my program choked... Please help...

```
Node ListToTree(Node head)
{
    if(head == NULL)
        return NULL;

    Node hleft = NULL, hright = NULL;

    Node root = head;

    hleft = ListToTree(head->left);
    head->left = NULL;
    root->left = hleft;

    hright = ListToTree(head->right);
    head->right = NULL;
    root->right = hright;

    return root;
}
```

Comment: middle of a "Circularly doubly linked list"? Think about it ...

Comment: Need a reference to the original head and make sure right and left are not equal to it o.O

Comment: Also I am gonna guess by choking you meant that your program crashed with a stack overflow.

Comment: Heh! Do you mean the median? Or do you mean the mean? Or what? I don't mean to be be mean about it.

Comment: @pmg - i am trying the same logic, middle of linked list... But could not able to figure out the recursive steps. can you help...

Comment: So you want to go from doubly linked-list to a BST, correct? I'm merely asking cuz that link above was the opposite. Anyways, how about breaking the cycle in the doubly linked-list by setting one node.next == null plus other accommodations. Set the head ptr too btw, and walk down the line to build your BST

Comment: Programming Interviews Exposed has an excellent explanation for this question.

Comment: In order to create a binary search tree, you need a comparison operator on the elements you store. Did you think about that? Otherwise, you can only create an arbitray binary tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Node {
  Node *prev, *next;
  int value;
}

void listToTree(Node * head) {
    if (head == null)
        return;
    if (head->next == head) {
        head->prev = null;
        head->next = null;
        return head;
    }
    if (head->next->next == head) {
        head->prev = null;
        head->next->next = null;
        head->next->prev = null;
        return head;
    }

    Node *p1 = head, *p2 = head->prev;
    while (p1->value < p2.value)
        p1 = p1->next, p2 = p2->prev;
    Node * root = p1;
    root->prev->next = head;
    root->next->prev = head->prev;
    root->prev = listToTree(head);
    root->next = listToTree(root->next);
    return root;
}
```

Comment: And I assume that list isn't sorted, so every element is inserted to the tree in O(log n) time.

Comment: List is sorted...... And have to be done, without using extra memmory... Just tweaking with pointers, this is achievable. I am trying to figure it out... read the URL that i posted in the question, and you will get an idea...

Comment: I've updated my code, check this. It works again in O(n log n) but without additional memory.